# Strange cmd calls without parent process

Tags: windows

Today I found a strange occurrence, around 18 conhost open at the startup with no parent process.  ProcMon shows that console window was created by this command:

```
cmd /k netstat -ano|findstr 5069
```

but I can't find what or who called this process.

Also I tried killing these processes, but they keep popping up.

Where can I find the culprit or what can I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It ended up being the phone software from Huawei. I ended up uninstalling it